# Add discount code and gift card form to multi shipping checkout

Tags: magento2, multishipping

can anyone help me to add discount code and gift card form to multi shipping checkout page near to payment methods.

I want to add discount code form and gift card form instead of this "*Add or remove gift cards* " link.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you got any solution on this?

Comment: Not got any solutions  :(